# Thread.Join versus Task.Wait

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

Consider the following code.

### Thread

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(Foo);
    t.Start();

    Console.WriteLine("Main ends.");
    //t.Join();
}

static void Foo()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 1000000000; x++) ;

    Console.WriteLine("Foo ends.");
}
```

### Task

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task t = new Task (Foo);
    t.Start();

    Console.WriteLine("Main ends.");
    t.Wait();
}

static void Foo()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 1000000000; x++) ;

    Console.WriteLine("Foo ends.");
}
```

When using `Task`, we need `t.Wait()` to wait for the thread pool thread to complete before the main thread ends but when using `Thread`, we don't need `t.Join` to get the same effect.

## Question

Why is `t.Join()` not needed to prevent the main thread from ending before the other spawned threads end?

Comment: Now set `IsBackground` property of Thread to true and test it again....

Comment: @L.B: Good point!

Comment: The first example (with the Thread class) waits until the thread finishes since Thread, by default, doesn't run on the background, as opposed to Task.
The Task is based on a thread-pool concept, which runs on the background by nature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several differences, but the important part to answer your question is that the thread pool uses background threads, and these do not block the process from exiting. You can read more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I would rather say to read more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Threading.Thread.IsBackground);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true)

Answer (score -1):

t.wait() could not be used after a task is already started.

Comment: What is the `t`? Is it a `Task` or a `Thread`?